# What happens if you hire both Meryn and Shiki?

Tags: fiz

Meryn's flavour text states that she "Doesn't get along well with Shiki." However, Shiki's does not mention Meryl.

Does anything special happen if I hire both of them?

Comment: Preliminary observations: nothing ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing.  I've hired both of them before and made huge batches of beer.

Comment: I think I remember seeing that their passive bonuses don't stack, but I'm not sure (and I've since deleted that save). Can you check for me?

Comment: @Schism I will double check but I'm pretty sure I've gotten an extra big batch

Comment: @schism I can confirm they stack.  I just had a batch yield of 250%